# Does @Loader work correctly on annotations (using JPA)?

Tags: hibernate

This is a somewhat contrived example meant to show a point. Here are two entity classes linked by a relationship and a named query:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "loadFoo",
              query = "select * from foos where bar_id = ?",
              resultClass = Foo.class)                  
public class Bar {
@Id private int id;

@ManyToOne @Loader(namedQuery = "loadFoo") private Foo foo;

public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

public int getId() { return id; }

public void setFoo(Foo foo) { this.foo = foo; }

public Foo getFoo() { return foo; }
}
```

And then:

```
@Entity @Table(name="foos")
public class Foo {
@Id @GeneratedValue private int id;

@Column(name="bar_id") private int barId;

public void setBarId(int barId) { this.barId = barId; }

public int getBarId() { return barId; }

public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

public int getId() { return id; }
}
```

The odd thing is that the named query works just fine in unit testing:

Here's the setup:

```
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    entityManager.persist(bar);
    entityManager.flush();

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setBarId(bar.getId());

    entityManager.persist(foo);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();
```

And this correctly returns Foo, so there does not appear to be a problem with the named query:

```
    Foo foo2 = (Foo) entityManager.createNamedQuery("loadFoo").setParameter(1, bar.getId()).getSingleResult();
```

But the load does not:

```
    Bar bar2 = entityManager.find(Bar.class, bar.getId());
    Foo foo3 = bar2.getFoo();       
    assertEquals(foo2.getId(), foo3.getId());
```

There are no errors thrown. The returned object is simply null. The @Loader annotation is in fact being processed by the persistence unit, because if I make the named query invalid, an exception will be thrown when getFoo() is called. But it never returns a correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Loader can only apply on a class or on a collection, not on a @*ToOne.
In your case, you would need to put the @Loader annotation on top of class Foo.

Comment: Is there any way of doing what I am trying to do here, in effect creating a "virtual" attribute loaded (lazily or eagerly, I don't care) with some arbitrary SQL? Maybe a @SecondaryTable annotation with @Loader placed on it? The problem I foresee there is AFAIK @SecondaryTable really requires there to be a table and not just some arbitrary SQL that returns a representation.

Comment: BTW, thank you for your help, Emmanuel. It's great to get help from the master. Maybe the best I can do if I want a "virtual" attribute is not use an entity at all, but rather a named query with a sql result set mapping. Not sure.

Comment: yes I think formula can be used even for @ManyToOne (using @JoinColumnOrFormula). I'm not sure it would solve your specific problem but it's very likely.